# Play on Mac 4.4.4 doing nothing on button press

Tags: virtualization, games, wine

I recently installed PlayOnMac 4.4.4 on my MacOS Big Sur (11.7.10). Hardware wise, it's a mid-2013 Macbook Air that is still very functional despite its age. When I'm clicking through the graphical interface to install a program, I find the one I'm looking for on the window labelled "PlayOnMac install menu," highlight it in the list, and hit "install." And then... nothing happens. No error message, nothing. Tried looking for error logs in my ~/Library/PlayOnMac/logs folder but didn't find anything.

Additionally, when I click the "configure" button in the first window when I start PlayOnMac, again nothing happens. The button darkens momentarily to indicate that a click has occured, and then nothing.

What's up with that? System compatibility problems? Are there additional steps to the installation process that I need to get through? I know that PlayOnMac is based on another program called Wine, not really sure how to configure and troubleshoot that.

Thanks, everyone, for tolerating a noob question!